# React component does not render, path is correct

Tags: reactjs

for some reason i cant seem to render my about page instead of the home page,
routing seems correct, url changes correctly however the render doesnt happen,
the components are imported correctly.

When i click home i see '/#/' in the url,

And When i click about i see: /#/about respectively at the end.

the main app:

```
 <Router>
    <Switch>
      <div className="wrapper">
        <NavBar></NavBar>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <footer>Footer</footer>
      </div>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

The Nav:

```
<NavLink exact to="/">
  Home
</NavLink>
<NavLink exact to="/about">
  About
</NavLink>
```

The About:

```
export function About(){
    return(
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Switch](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch) will render the first matching `Route` and not render any others. `/about` will match `/`, so it will only render `Home`.

You can fix this by adding the [exact](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool) keyword to your Switch routes. This will make it so that the path will have to match exactly, which will result in skipping `/` when navigating to `/about`.

---

I also think it might make more sense to move the `Navbar` out of the `Switch`.